# How does the program 'remember' the temporary object?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, copy-constructor, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    int first;
    int last;
    A(int x = 0, int y = 0):first(x), last(y){}
    A(A&a) { cout << "c ctor \n"; }
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, A b) {
    os << "first:" << b.first << "  last:" << b.last << endl;
    return os;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& is, A a) {
    is >> a.first >> a.last;
    return is;
}
int main()
{
    A i;
    cout << "enter first and last: \n";
    cin >> i;
    cout << i;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

A a is a new A object in the >> overload, and if we enter 6 4 into it, the program will remember it in the << overload function, and print what we entered into it. Can someone explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Your program is buggy due to the `A` copy constructor not actually making copies.

Comment: But the program runs fine. The copy constructor doesn't copy the values of i into a, but a still exists as an A object, and I can enter values into it in the >>overload function(where it's created)

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land.  Anything can happen there

Comment: @Steve_ Your program is passing `A` by value, thus a copy will be made.  But you overrode the compiler's default copy constructor with your own buggy version that doesn't make copies.  One of the hardest bugs to track down is the one you are making right now, and that is a program that makes bogus copies.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that should probably be an answer. I'll upvote it

Comment: So why does the program 'remember' the numbers I entered into a, and prints them in the << operator? How does it know about the numbers I entered, if they weren't entered into 'i'?

Comment: Btw It's buggy on purpose; It's a question from a test;

Comment: *So why does the program 'remember' the numbers I entered into a, and prints them in the << operator?* -- Are you familiar with what "undefined behavior" is in C++?

Comment: @Steve_ in `A(A&a) { cout << "c ctor \n"; }` you don't actually initialize anything. Then you try to read the memory you never initialized, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Never heard of that...

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen.  That "anything" could be that the program works today, and bombs out next week.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detailed answer

Comment: `stream& operator>>(istream& is, A a)` should be `stream& operator>>(istream& is, A& a)`

Comment: I didnt find a good duplicate, but here is a quite comprehensive list of causes of UB:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/367662/4117728

Comment: If you want some explanation of what's happening beyond 'It's undefined behavior' you can look at the actual code your compiler has generated, all you answers will be there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wrong statement relative to your presented code because the operator >> deals with a copy of the original object used as an argument of the operator.

The operator should be declared like

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, A &a) {
    is >> a.first >> a.last;
    return is;
}
```

And moreover the copy constructor does not copies data members.

So the program has undefined behavior.  For example running it using clang HEAD 11.0.0 you can get the following result

```
prog.cc:8:9: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
    A(A&a) { cout << "c ctor \n"; }
        ^
1 warning generated.
enter first and last: 
c ctor 
c ctor 
first:4202496  last:0
```

That is the program outputs the variables first and last with indeterminate values because the data members of the created object `b` in the operator << were not initialized.

Comment: I know, I just want to understand why the numbers I enter in the >> operator get saved, and printed in the << operator function.

Comment: @Steve_ As you can see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7JpEoZARZErOz3w6) and [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OHnUuIFNoLJd7Wh1) they aren't saved. It's undefined behavior. Anything can happen. Different compilers generate different code.

Comment: not using parameter `a` is not what causes UB, the warning could be silenced via `A(A& a) { cout << a; }`, while the UB would be gone with `A(A& a) : first(0),last(0) {}`

Comment: @idclev463035818 The problem is that the data members are not initialized.

Comment: i know, I am just saying that `A(A& a) : first(0),last(0) {}` does initialize them but still does not make a copy